# How to get the search button to work after a query is submitted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I have created a search option on my app where when a query is entered into the search bar and the search button is pressed, it will bring the results. But when I try to do it again, it does not search. I will stay on the last results.

Here is the code that is activated when the search button is pressed.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *query = [googleBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    UIWebView *webview3=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/server.bithumor.co/search/index1.php?query=%@", query]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview3 loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webview3];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:webview3];

    webview3.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [self webviewListen:webview3];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

 googleBar.delegate = self;

}
```

Why is this not working after the first time and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add webview again and again for every search.

Try the following steps.

i) Declare a webview property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
```

ii) Add the webview in ViewDidLoad method.

```
CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.searchBar.frame);
frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(self.searchBar.bounds);

self.webView =[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.searchBar];
```

iii) In searchBarSearchButtonClicked method add the following code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/server.bithumor.co/search/index1.php?query=%@", query]];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not receive any errors, but now the search bar does not appear